# Why is $\frac{1}{1+(\frac{-\sin x}{1+\cos x})^2} \equiv \frac{(1+\cos x)^2}{\sin^2x+1+2\cos x+\cos^2x}$?

Tags: trigonometry, rational-functions

Currently I have a problem to understand why $$\frac{1}{1+(\frac{-\sin x}{1+\cos x})^2} \equiv \frac{(1+\cos x)^2}{\sin^2x+1+2\cos x+\cos^2x}\,?$$

My calculations get me:

$$\frac{1}{1+(\frac{-\sin x}{1+\cos x})^2}\equiv \frac{(1+\cos x)^2}{1+\sin^2x}.$$

Why is this not correct? We have a rational number in the denumerator. Thus the numerator of this rational number should move above. The other formula did this too. But why is there $2\cos x+\cos^2x$?

Thanks in advance! Stay healthy!

Comment: The denominator isn't in a fractional form as you've written it, because you have $1+\frac{...}{...}$, so if you want to pull off your logic you need  to combine the $1$ into the fraction using a common denominator. After that, everything you've said will work, and that will lead to a healthy outcome. That didn't happen in the other formula : in the other formula, either the $1$ was combined like I said above, or both numerator and denominator were multiplied by the same quantity, like Jean-Claude demonstrated below.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked my logic with wolfram, so this rule is only applicable, if the denumerators are multiplications. Due to the addition, this is not applicable and we have to baseline the 1 with the rational part. Thanks! It is something, that I get wrong quite often..

Comment: It comes with practice, the main takeaway is that you have to finish all the additions and get one fraction on the denominator, before you can take the appropriate part above. The answer below didn't reflect that exactly but still showed that a different way of thinking about it can help avoid using that rule of taking some part above, and make the whole simplification feel a little more natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you multiply the numerator and the denominator by $(1+\cos x)^2$, you get:

$$\frac{1}{1+(\frac{-\sin x}{1+\cos x})^2}=\frac{(1+\cos x)^2}{(1+\cos x)^2}\times\frac{1}{1+(\frac{-\sin x}{1+\cos x})^2}=\frac{(1+\cos x)^2}{(1+\cos x)^2\left(1+(\frac{-\sin x}{1+\cos x})^2\right)}\\=\frac{(1+\cos x)^2}{(1+\cos x)^2+\sin^2x}$$